# adding div in jquery does not perform as if it is written directly by html

Tags: jquery, html

html code:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var queryString = (window.location.href).substr((window.location.href).indexOf('?') + 1);
    var value = (queryString.split('='))[1];        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/phoneGap/AnyScan/www/image.php?typeID="+value,function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                $(".swiper-wrapper").append("<div class='swiper-slide'><a href='http://localhost/anyscan/images/"+field.content+"'><img src='http://localhost/anyscan/images/"+field.content+"' width='100%' height='100%'></a></div>");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am using an external file for swiping between pictures, every image should be in a  which is a part of a div with class swiper-wrapper as shown below :

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
       <div class=swiper-slide>image 1</div>
       <div class=swiper-slide>image 2</div>
       <div class=swiper-slide>image 3</div>
       <div class=swiper-slide>image 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I use the jquery code the images doesn't swipe unless I minimize the browser and maximize it (I don't know why), but if I put the links of image inside the html like this:

```
<div class="swiper-slide"><a href='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-30182012-08-12-133.jpg'><img src='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-30182012-08-12-133.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'></a></div>
<div class="swiper-slide"><a href='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-59071hyt%20002.jpg'><img src='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-59071hyt%20002.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'></a></div>
<div class="swiper-slide"><a href='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-11955hyt%20003.jpg'><img src='http://localhost/anyscan/images/icon-11955hyt%20003.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'></a></div>
```

it works perfectly, any help ?

Comment: are you using any plugin to provide the swipe functionality

Comment: yes i am using wriper-master plugin

Comment: How do you initialize the [swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/) plugin, do you have something like `var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');` in your page

Comment: yes of course:  var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container');

Comment: the page load and the first image is shown but when i swipe it does not work unless i minimize and maximize the browser

Comment: You should initialize the plugin again after you insert the images in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to call the `onResize()` or `update()` method after adding the contents to the slider

```
var queryString = (window.location.href).substr((window.location.href).indexOf('?') + 1);
var value = (queryString.split('='))[1];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("http://localhost/phoneGap/AnyScan/www/image.php?typeID=" + value, function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      $(".swiper-wrapper").append("<div class='swiper-slide'><a href='http://localhost/anyscan/images/" + field.content + "'><img src='http://localhost/anyscan/images/" + field.content + "' width='100%' height='100%'></a></div>");
    });
    swiper.update();
  });
});
```